# ListView row gets smaller on adding a new view programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm implementing a custom list view adapter to make a multiple selection listview with check boxes.

The problem is when adding the check box on getView() methods within adapter, the row makes height smaller.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context context = getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(mCellResourceId, parent, false);
    T element = getItem(position);

    if (mEditMode) {
        LinearLayout linearLay = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.widget_frame);
        CheckBox check = new CheckBox(mContext);
        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);            
        linearLay.addView(check, 0);
    }

    setDataToRow(element, rowView);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: looks like you're inflating from xml,  I'd say add that checkbox to the xml and set as gone, then if edit mode set to visible.

Comment: set layout parameters to Checkbox.